# This Prophesy of Prophet Muhammad in Hagai

Tags: prophet-muhammad, judaism, bible

The following verse in the Torah prophesizes about a nation which will be given "peace" and coming of a praised being:

> and I will shake all nations, and the choicest things of all nations(חֶמְדַּת )
>   shall come, and I will fill this house with glory, saith the LORD of
>   hosts. 8 Mine is the silver, and Mine the gold, saith the LORD of
>   hosts. 9 The glory of this latter house shall be greater than that of
>   the former, saith the LORD of hosts; and in this place will I give
>   peace(שָׁלוֹם), saith the LORD of hosts.' [Haggai 2](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/e/et/et2202.htm)

There is  a remarkable appearance of the word חֶמְדַּת having root H-M-D. The arabic root for this is given [here](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D8%AD_%D9%85_%D8%AF) as Form IV: أَحْمَدَ (ʼáħmada)

Also its said that the nation will be great and shake all other nations and God will give the nation "(שָׁלוֹם)"(Sh-L-M is a  root for Islam).

I understand that prophecies seem to be very cryptic until when the prophecy actually happens , and the verses become clear after the prophecy is manifested. Hence i guess only the ones who are very firmly grounded in knowledge would give us a clue to understand the above verse? And even they can go wrong in interpreting the verses as God alone would know its true meaning.

Have any past Islamic scholars analysed this verse of  Torah for such prophesies of  Muhammad pbuh ?

Answer (score 2):

Taken out of context.

"and I will shake all nations, and the choicest **things of all nations**(חֶמְדַּת ),"
This is a reference to a **particular event**, not a human. It shouldn't surprise you that Hebrew and Arabic have similar words. Nearly every Arabic word has an identical looking Hebrew consonant. The same process can be used for Jesus, even more so, because his name(Yehoshua') is in the bible **dozens of times in plain Hebrew**. For example, it was Yehoshua'(Commander of the LORD) who led Israel into Jerusalem when Moses died. He conquered all of Palestine and established the seat of power. What bigger prophecy do you need???

" and I will fill this house with glory, saith the LORD of hosts. "
What house? The house of Solomon that Jehovah was preaching in nearly every page of the Bible!!! Muhammad changed the land of promise to **Mecca**, how can it be in His house? Think about it, please!

*Hence i guess only the ones who are very firmly grounded in knowledge would give us a clue to understand the above verse? And even they can go wrong in interpreting the verses as God alone would know its true meaning.*

Rashad Khalifa misinterperated biblical verses to say he was the Messenger of the Covenant. Why don't Muslims believe his message? WHat about Mirza Ahmad? See, how it works...

*Have any past Islamic scholars analysed this verse of Torah for such prophesies of Muhammad pbuh ?*
Yes they did, and they misconstrued the Quran to make these prophecies true. For example, the Quran never says that Abraham and Ishmael went to Arabia, are Muhammad's fathers, etc. But people like Ibn Abbas made stories to fulfill Bible prophecies.

PS. I'm a devout Muslim. I like the truth.

Comment: I like your answer and I believe it's wrong to tailor bible messages just to make it suit prophecies

Answer (score 0):

Replying to the 1 that said that the message isn’t true. How do you know Hebrew it’s a little bit suspicious and how could you ever see Ismail never went to Arabia then, how did him and Abraham built? The kaaba.
Things like that, let any Muslim be suspicious and question your face. It will never say Arabia directly because Arabia wasn’t a word back. so how could you say he didn’t go to Arabia when the world itself didn’t exist back then word Arab was Romanised 2000 years ago, Abraham and Ishmael live 4000 years ago, so how could you speak with such tenderness it only makes me question your face to be honest.